Oracle of the lord: why is it repeated so often?
To me, it sounds very weird that the words "Oracle of the lord" are being repeated so often, even in the same sentence, and when it is clear from the context that what is being said is an "Oracle of the lord".
As an example, consider Jeremiah, 31,16-17:

Thus says the Lord:
Cease your cries of weeping,
hold back your tears!
There is compensation for your labor—
oracle of the Lord—
they shall return from the enemy’s land.
There is hope for your future—oracle of the Lord—
your children shall return to their own territory.

It's clear that Lord is speaking, nevertheless the phrase —oracle of the Lord— is repeated twice after few words.
This seems to me not to be a stylistic feature (but I may be wrong, of course!), as such repetitions seem not to occur for other phrases; they also occur in other books. Also, isn't it too exaggerated as an emphasis (consider how often it occurs: e. g.: I count 9 times only in Jeremiah, 31,31-38!)?
Is there a deeper meaning in those particular words? Something I'm not able to get?

Let me quote Jer 31:16, 17 from the ESV:

Thus says the LORD: “Keep your voice from weeping, and your eyes from
tears, for there is a reward for your work, declares the LORD, and
they shall come back from the land of the enemy. There is hope for
your future, declares the LORD, and your children shall come back
to their own country.

The OP appears to be asking about the Hebrew word נְאֻם (ne'um) = "utterance".  The only version I can find that translates this word "oracle" is the NAB.  However, this is clearly awkward and most versions render it, especially when it precedes "LORD" (most often) as "says", or, "declares".
The latter is a more faithful idiomatic rendering.

Most relevant to our understanding of God’s Word, when we read “Thus saith the LORD!” it reinforces and emphasizes the authority of God.  We are reminded that God is omnipotent (having unlimited power), sovereign (supreme in authority), and immutable (does not change).  God’s Word is Truth and God is faithful – forever.
Isaiah 40:8

The grass withereth, the flower fadeth: but the word of our God shall stand for ever.

Psalm 119:89

For ever, O LORD, thy word is settled in heaven.

Matthew 24:35

Heaven and earth shall pass away, but my words shall not pass away.

There are stylistic features employed in the Bible that may have been more common in the original Hebrew language.  This style might have been more natural to the original hearers as compared to us reading in English, and it may have made it easier to remember and recite in cultures where printing was not available.  It is especially unnatural when these are translated inconsistently as in the text provided in the question. There is another answer that addresses this.
Ultimately though, this expression used in the Old Testament more than 800 times conveys the same thing to us as when it was written:  This is God’s Word.  God has something He wants us to hear.  Listen up.
